# Java Remote API and the (Experimental) Federated Login

Tags: google-app-engine

I've been successfully using the [Remote API for Java](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi?hl=en) in a standalone client and some time ago switched my app to use the experimental Federated Login. Now I am getting the `can't get appId from remote api; status code = 302` exceptions every time my standalone client connects to the app.

I am looking for a confirmation of whether (or not) the Remote API for Java works with the Federated Login, to know whether the problem is on my side or a current limitation of GAE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some additional searching it appears that there's indeed an acknowledged problem with the use of Federated Login and Remote API, accepted as the [issue 5165](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5165&q=Type=Defect%20remote%20api&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log) by the App Engine team.